# how to solve these my error exception?

Tags: sql, plsql

how to solve this error

```
create or replace package pg1
as
procedure p1(p_deptno in number);
type t is table of emp%rowtype
index by binary_integer;
end pg1;
    create or replace package body pg1
    as
    procedure p1(p_deptno in number)
    as
    v_emp t;
    v_dep exception;
    begin
    begin
    select * bulk collect into v_emp from emp where deptno=p_deptno;
    if p_deptno=10 then
    raise v_dep;
    end if;
    for i in v_emp.first..v_emp.last
    loop
    insert into pg values(v_emp(i).empno, v_emp(i).ename, v_emp(i).job, v_emp(i).mgr, v_emp(i).hiredate, v_emp(i).sal, v_emp(i).comm, v_emp(i).deptno);
    end loop;
    exception
    when v_dep then
    raise_application_error(-20200,'my exception raised');
    raise value_error;
    end
    when value_error then/*here getting error*/
    dbms_output.put_line('value error');
    end;
    end p1;
    end pg1;
    end;
```

> 23/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one
>   of
>            the following:
>            ;

Comment: missing semi-colon on the line before "when..."

Answer (score 0):

First always try to evaluate what error does oracle throws. Oracle errors are very descriptive inmost of the cases. Here if you see carefully it always points to the exact line number too. Hope you will try to debug next time onwards :)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pg1
AS
  PROCEDURE p1(
      p_deptno IN NUMBER);
type t
IS
  TABLE OF emp%rowtype INDEX BY binary_integer;
END pg1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body pg1
AS
  PROCEDURE p1(
      p_deptno IN NUMBER)
  AS
    v_emp t;
    v_dep EXCEPTION;
  BEGIN
    BEGIN
      SELECT * bulk collect INTO v_emp FROM emp WHERE deptno=p_deptno;
      IF p_deptno=10 THEN
        raise v_dep;
      END IF;
      FOR i IN v_emp.first..v_emp.last
      LOOP
        INSERT
        INTO pg VALUES
          (
            v_emp(i).empno,
            v_emp(i).ename,
            v_emp(i).job,
            v_emp(i).mgr,
            v_emp(i).hiredate,
            v_emp(i).sal,
            v_emp(i).comm,
            v_emp(i).deptno
          );
      END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN v_dep THEN
      raise_application_error(-20200,'my exception raised');
      raise value_error;
    END; -- Missed semi colon here
  WHEN value_error THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('value error');
  END;
END p1;
END pg1;
END;
```